# python 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decompose'

Tags: python, html, web, web-scraping, web-crawler

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
#import requests
import urllib.request,re
#import pandas as pd
#import numpy as np
import csv

def crawlcontents():
    url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g983296-i13236-k11538516-Rent_from_LOTTE_standard_or_mystery_option-Jeju_Island.html' 

    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode() 

#    print(html)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
#    print(soup)
    div = soup.select_one('#SHOW_TOPIC > div.balance > div.firstPostBox > div > div > div.postRightContent > div.postcontent > div.postBody')
    div.select_one('script').decompose() 

    postcontent = div.text.strip()
    postcontent = re.sub(r'\n+', ' ',postcontent)
    print(postcontent)

crawlcontents()
```

This is crawling in trip site.
I need a script but, the error is:

> python 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decompose'

how do I change that?

Comment: Why are you yelling? What is the actual traceback you get?

Comment: Can you explain what the line with the call to `.decompose()` is trying to accomplish? The `div` variable doesn't contain any `script` CSS selector, so when you try and select it using `select_one` it returns None, hence the error you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm supposing you want "mystery option seems to have a great price deal - but you do not know what car you would get which one do you take? will it turn out ok?" as the output right? You're trying to use decompose to remove the tags, but that isn't necessary.

If that's the output you want, "div" is a resultset. I don't suppose you can run select_one on it again. You don't even need re in this instance. Try this:

```
#Remove the below
div.select_one('script').decompose()

#Include the below
postcontent = div[0].text.strip().replace('\n',' ')
```

You have to use the element div[0] rather than the resultset div. strip() removes whitespaces at the ends, while the replace removes whitespaces between the two comment strings.